# How to let PyCharm/IntelliJ handle a specific hotkey rather than IdeaVim?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, ideavim

I've installed IdeaVim in PyCharm and in IntelliJ and I'd like to set the editors to handle certain key events. How can I do that?

Previously, I've seen a popup with a message like "You just pressed x+y and it was handled by IdeaVim. If you'd like to have PyCharm handle this instead, click here" - and then I'd click there for the cases where I wanted PyCharm to handle it. But now I don't see that popup, and I can't figure out where I can set this manually.

Comment: FYI IdeaVim shows the pop-up once for each conflicting shortcut when you use it for the first time.

Comment: I was used to that actually, but in this case it didn't for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course I figured this out one minute after posting. You can do it in Settings -> Other settings -> Vim emulation.

[image]